# Firestore - Is creating instance multiple times a good option?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

While using Firebase Firestore, I was building some queries in functions in a single file as service so I can use all queries from single file instead of creating all functions in different files where they are needed.

Like -
Created 1 file with 4 functions - createUser, getUser, deleteUser, updateUser.

Now, Here's What I was thinking about approach to follow -

`APPROA 1 -> Creating Global instance and using that in functions`

```
const db = firebase.firestore();

const createUser = function() {
    db.collection("users").add(data)
        .then(function (docRef) {
            console.log(docRef)
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });
}

const update = function() {
    db.collection("users")...//Code to update
}
```

`APPROACH 2 -> Creating instance in each function`

```
const createUser = function(argument) {
    const db = firebase.firestore();

    db.collection("users").add(data)
        .then(function (docRef) {
            console.log(docRef)
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });
}

const createUser = function() {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    db.collection("users")...//Code to update
}
```

Will there be any difference in performance that can vary in 2 given approaches? Or they both are same? That will not impact on memory if created in each function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`firebase.firestore()` returns a singleton object. There is no performance impact to calling it after it's already been called.  Do whatever you personally prefer, but your ability to unit test code might be impacted by your decision.  But again, it's entirely up to you.